# android tablet arabic language support

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, arabic

I am using Samsung Galaxy Tab and my app contains displaying Arabic texts. I have 2 rows that displays texts. One row will display in Arabic and other in English. The output will look 
like

[image]

Some space is coming in front of the Arabic text. I have given these two text inside a `tablelayout`. But if I am displaying the text in English instead of Arabic then this extra space won't be there. Why is it so? Is that related to Arabic language?

Comment: Could you share your some code.. I also want to have Arabic support in my app and test it on Galaxy tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Arabic is a right to left script. So nothing to worry.