# Android TextView gravity

Tags: android, textview, arabic, gravity

I'm writing app for devices with Android 3.0 and up. It is arabic app.

By default platform aligns arabic text right (even in Dialogs) and English text left.

But When I'm setting gravity="right" for arabic text it aligns left.

Another problem comes from some devices (for example, some Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1, NOT ALL!).
Looks like they fixed it and now it aligns arabic text left by default!

How can I fix it?

Comment: Basically Arabic language start from right to left script. check this  link.

[Yes, Arabic is a right to left script. So nothing to worry.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387221/android-tablet-arabic-language-support)

Comment: Ok, let's accept that arabic is RTL. But why gravity="right" aligns it left?

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14529

Comment: same thing happening for me also. in addition In Edit text if i give the Gravity as RIGHT, its writing from Right to Left when user typing, But hint is getting displayed at Left side. And if I give the Gravity as LEFT Hint is getting Displayed at Right side. But writing user inputs from Left to Right. So Can Someone suggest some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround is to:
  1. remove the `android:gravity` value.
  2. set the `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content`.
  3. set the `android:layout_gravity` to whatever logical value you want.

this works fine with `TextView` because it does not have any content except text.

other than that, i don't know.

anyway it's reported as bug to google
see this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14529